# AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'SSLError'

Tags: python, embedded-linux

I'm trying a python script to write to a mysql database on a very basic linux system, but I get this error. I use mysql-connector-python v 8.0.21.

I use python 3.5.0

My guess is that an old ssl library is installed and hence this error.

I cannot install (apt-get) or compile something with "make", because this system does not have these commands.
Only thing I can do is through ftp copy the libraries into the right place.

I also found a "libssl.so.1.0.2" in the /usr/lib directory. maybe I have to replace this one with a newer version?

for now I only try to open a mysql database :

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
        host="localhost",
        port=3306,
        user="user",
        password="userPassword",
        database="logging"
    )
```

error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 445,                                                                                                                                                              in switch_to_ssl
    cert_reqs = ssl.CERT_NONE
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'CERT_NONE'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PLC_domotica.py", line 64, in <module>
    database="logging"
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 265,                                                                                                                                                              in connect
    return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 10                                                                                                                                                             4, in __init__
    self.connect(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 966                                                                                                                                                             , in connect
    self._open_connection()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 29                                                                                                                                                             2, in _open_connection
    self._ssl, self._conn_attrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 20                                                                                                                                                             1, in _do_auth
    ssl_options.get('tls_versions'))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 521,                                                                                                                                                              in switch_to_ssl
    except (ssl.SSLError, IOError) as err:
AttributeError: module 'ssl' has no attribute 'SSLError'
```

Comment: What version of Python are you running?

Comment: python 3.5.0 is installed on the system

Comment: It should not give you that error then because the `ssl` library for Python v.3.5 does have that attribute. See this link https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ssl.html#ssl.SSLError


Another way to ensure that it does is by creating a test file and see if it can print the `ssl.SSLError`. Use `import ssl` on top and then add `print(ssl.SSLError)`

If the program runs without any error and prints `<class 'ssl.SSLError'>` then there's no issue with the `ssl` library. Perhaps re-installing `mysql-connector` may help.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is `ssl.py` file or directory in project, that conflict module name with system ssl module. Make sure that there is no files have names like python lib and site-packages.

Comment: This is silly but I didn't realize someone put into the repository a ssl.py file (empty) why? No idea but by removing this, it works as expected